# open source scorm player pure javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, scorm

Is there any scorm player which is purely based on the javascript and html . i do,t wanna use any server side languages for it . I found an open source [Scormpool](http://www.scormpool.com) but it is just playing the scorm its not tracking . and no documentation is available . If you guys know any please help .

Comment: yes a bit . but not fully :(

Answer (score 7):

This may get you started as well, or you can tailor it to your own needs.

**https://github.com/skfriese/simple-scorm-api**

It's a *rudimentary* SCORM 1.2-only RTE test environment in a single HTML file that I whipped up for my own needs years ago. I only recently elected to clean it up to share with others. It's easy to throw into your package folder and spin up from there. The SCO will assume it's running in an LMS, which is really all that's necessary for testing most of the time.

You can update the default values in the Javascript, and the data will be stored in LocalStorage or fall back to cookies if necessary. It will also "attempt" to read some values from a manifest, should one exist. It does not support multi-SCO packages or any other complex organizational features of SCORM.

The Reload Tools have been embedded into the page as well, so you'll find that most of the data elements will be validated.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: thank you very much for that initial file. One thing I want to ask you did you implement Scorm 2004 and do you have the cleaner version? If yes I may need those also I need your help to understand Some of the Scorm concept

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for similar solution myself and was unable to find anything.

So after struggling with docs and bits found online I have created this:

https://bitbucket.org/jugger0/tsp

It is far away from a fully-featured player but can be used as a starting point.

Maybe someone will find it useful.

Comment: You can try but this was a long time ago and I never used it since so I might not be able to help. code is pretty trivial though.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if the desired result was better defined. Do you just want to be able to run scorm content locally without errors?

The initial question mentions that the content is playing but not tracking... where would it track to? Are you looking to have things stored for later retrieval on the same system, or potentially on any system? If this is the case, where would it be stored? In the browser (single system only and prone to deletion with clearing cookies, cache, etc), or to a server (accessible from multiple systems)?

If to a server, it is going to require at least some server side language, though you could potentially use something like node.js which would let that language still be javascript.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I am facing the same problem. I have a scorm package, and if I run the index.html file there, it plays the scorm content. But I need to track the process of each user like how many videos inside a scorm content the user has seen, how many assignments he has finished and how well he did those and store these details in database on server. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Claude Ostyn's SCORM 1.2 Test Wrap will act as a standalone in-memory "LMS" for SCORM 1.2 courses.

There is some setup required; though it will work if you run it directly in the browser, you may find it more effective running it (and your course) from a webserver.

Available here: https://www.jcasolutions.com/development/code-repository/func-startdown/7/

This used to be part of a resource kit from Click2Learn.  Though Rustici (scorm.com) has adopted some of it, I wasn't able to find the original file there.

Instructions and more details may be found by running "launchme.html" directly.

I've found this one of my more valuable testing tools.

A SCORM 2004 version, and many more useful articles and tools may be found at Claude Ostyn's website http://www.ostyn.com.  He passed away several years ago, but someone has kindly kept the site up.

Comment: Ostyn link now dead - generic hosting page :(

Comment: Use archive.org... still there:  https://web.archive.org/web/20061014223831/http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/scorm2004testwrapwrap.htm