# How to create a simple Scorm Player using HTML & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I am new to SCORM & I am looking to create a simple SCORM player that just display the SCORM package content, no tracking n other things, only just play the content. I have searched  everywhere on internet but still no luck! Also I don't want to use anything like scorm.com engine and any other paid service. Moodle & Scormpool also did't help much. I want a code that plays scorm packages on my browser whether in html, javascript or php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So with no tracking and just "play the content" your essentially just launching a html file.
Any SCORM CAM Package typically has a imsmanifest.xml.  You'd need to be able to parse that, and then generate a one to many type Table Of Contents to present and play the content like you mention.  You can perform that in any of the desired scripting languages you mention.
Any open source project you find will most likely be very old or abandoned or have far too much dependancies to even bother with.  You simply want to know how to parse XML, built a TOC view, and manipulate launching the content in a IFRAME, new Window, Popup Window or Tab.

Comment: I have done that and successfully created a player to play the contents but, some scorm packages are asking for a connection to LMS. How to handle that packages? @Mark

Comment: Hi, your bumping up to needing to provide the SCORM Runtime API either version 1.2 or 2004 which require you to expose a namespace for the content to find.  This exceeds your desires mentioned prior but I can tell you if you don't care about persisting student data you can stub out rudimentary support.  This bumps up against the ADL white papers which support compliance and conformance.  But if you don't care about that stuff you just need to glean the basics of scorm to create a skeleton API in JavaScript only.  The prior answer supplies open source examples of their approach.

Comment: thanks for your help @Mark, I have created the player successfully. now I want to ask one more thing about uploading and extracting scorm zip packages. right now I am extracting the SCORM packages manually  and my index.html file(where my code to play SCORM files lies) finds the manifest file from there. But now i want to upload the zip file and play it automatically. I want to know how & where to extract the packages and how  to connect with the imsmanifest file extracted from the package.

Comment: You are just unzipping CAM/PIF packages which are zip files.  A normal LMS may validate the imsmanifest.xml which is why you can see many XSD/DTD documents in that package.  Any backend server side scripting language should be able to perform this task.  How you desire to build a content library is ultimately up to you.  Normally the imsmanifest.xml is in the root of every zip.  Sometimes the root of a zip is another folder, and then the imsmanifest.xml.  Just depends who made it.

Comment: Hi, I am new to scorm. I have a site of myself that has a video player in it. I would like my site to have a player that can play scorm files. Can you guide me how you implemented the scorm player?

Comment: There is some handy info I've compressed to work with the Content API I authored some time ago under a Creative Commons share-alike license.  This is not the LMS Runtime API for SCORM, but it collects a lot of information I can't elaborate on in this comment. https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at Trident IDE it is a SCORM authoring tool. If you already have a HTML or html5 interaction and you need it to load as a SCORM package you need a well defined manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate:
[open source scorm player pure javascript and html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018858/open-source-scorm-player-pure-javascript-and-html)

Here is a simple runtime environment you can set in your machine with a webserver. http://www.vsscorm.net/run-time-environment-rte/run-time-environment-downloads/

It requires to create database with one table, but it is more less self-guided.